# Felix bundles failng to load

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am attempting to run an application on Apache Felix, using the Felix Dependency bundles. The container is, for some reason, not loading my bundles.

I am doing my development using Bndtools in Eclipse. I am using the Amdatu bundles.

The bundles I am concerned about are the bundles that are in my "Run Requirements":

```
org.apache.felix.dependencymanager
org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell
org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.runtime
osgi.core
osgi.cmpn
```

All of the above bundles are taken from the Amdatu repository.

I have two bundles which I created:

```
com.test.demo.reader
com.test.demo.listener
```

And these bundles are built using org.apache.felix.dependencymanager and osgi.core.

When I attempt to run OSGi, I am getting the following failures:

```
! could not resolve the bundles: [com.test.demo.reader-1.0.0 Unresolved constraint in bundle 
com.test.demo.reader [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement 
[8.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.dm)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))),
com.test.demo.listener-1.0.0 Unresolved constraint in bundle com.test.demo.listener [9]:
Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.test.demo.reader)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) 
[caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.dm)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]]
```

and

```
! Failed to start bundle com.test.demo.reader-1.0.0, exception Unresolved constraint in
bundle com.test.demo.reader [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] 
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.dm)(version>=3.0.0)
(!(version>=4.0.0)))
```

and more

```
! Failed to start bundle com.test.demo.listener-1.0.0, exception Unresolved constraint in 
bundle com.test.demo.listener [9]: Unable to resolve 9.0: 
missing requirement [9.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.test.demo.reader)
(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement 
[8.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.dm)(version>=3.0.0)
(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
```

I think I understand what is happening: apparently the org.apache.dm package being used is a version that is somehow incompatible with my bundles. But that doesn't make any sense, because according to the Felix documentation the org.apache.dm package is in the org.apache.felix.dependencymanager bundle. That bundle is from the Amdatu repository and it is the only version of the bundle I am using with my application! How is the version incompatible with my bundles when theirs is the only version that my bundles know about???

Someone please advise. What is causing this failure an how can I fix it?

Comment: Are the 3 Felix DM bundles in an active/resolved state?  What versions are they, 3.0.0, 3.1.0 or 3.2.0?

Comment: The 3 bundles are apparently failing to resolve (based on the failure messages). I mistakenly thought it was in the runtime package but it is actually in the org.apache.felix.dependencymanager package (I will correct thisin my original post). The package version that came with the Amdatu bundle is 4.0.2 (I think). I suspect that I may need to find an earlier version. I will see if I can find one and do an update on what happens...

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the runtime I was running and what appears to be a bug in the Amdatu plugin.

I would not advise using the Amdatu configuration in your OSGi project. Not in its current form.

The various Felix Dependency bundles that I have been using from Amdatu are apparently intended to run under Felix version 5. Unfortunately, the Amdatu environment (the "Amdatu Configuration" that you can select when you choose a configuration template for your project) does not load Version 5. When you select the "Bundle- Hub configuration", your choice of runtime environments includes all Felix environments from Version 4.0.2 to Version 5.2, as well as several versions of Equinox. When you select the "Amdatu Configuration" you only runtime choices are Felix 4.0.2 and Felix 4.2.0.

I was using 4.2.0 Felix, and as a result the dependency bundles were not working.

The Amdatu environment in its current form is unusable in Bndtools. It apparently supplies the right bundles for Version 5 but does not provide that environment for the user.

I did try manually changing the runtime environment io Version 5.2. This did not work because apparently when you select a template, Bndtools puts together whatever runtimes are associated with the template. Because the Amdatu template does not include Felix version 5, the runtime environment is unavailable.

In order to get my application to run, I had to create a new project that used the "Bundle- Hub" template and manually download the dependency bundles from the Felix website and include them in my buil and runtime environments. Unfortunately, neither Bndtools nor Amdatu provides any way to add the Amdatu bundles to  project after a template is selected. This means that instead of using the ready- made bundles from Amdatu, you have to go out to the source sites and manually include them.

I will probably ty and find a way to create a new repository that can be included in projects and contains all the Amdatu bundles, then include that repository in the "Bundle- Hub" template. I will also report the problems with environments (as well as seversl other problems I've seen) to the Amdatu folks.

In the meantime, my application runs smoothly now that I have set up the right runtime environment.

Special thanks to earcam, whose questions in the comment above gave me a clue as to what to start looking at to solve this problem...

Comment: "Neither Bndtools... provides any way to add the bundles after a template is selected". Not true at all!! Just drag and drop bundles into your repo. There is also an "Add" button right on the toolbar. This kind of misinformation helps nobody.

Comment: Clarification: The bundles I was referring to are the Amdatu bundles that are provided with the Amdatu template. If you select the :Bundle-Hub" template, the repositories provided by the "Amdatu" template become inaccessible. Consequently there is no way to add the bundles in the Amdatu repositories once you select another template.

Comment: Still not remotely true! The templates are just starting points... you can add/remove repositories and add/remove bundles in your repositories after creating the workspace.

Comment: Please reread my clarification. It was pretty specific. I have stated that I cannot add Amdatu repositories after selecting the "Bundle-Hub" template. Instead of insisting otherwise without specifics, you might want to outline the exact steps for adding the Amdatu repositories after starting a bundle project using the "Bundle-Hub" template. There is no obvious way of doing that (having tried different methods and failing, I would be curious to know how you would do this). If you know otherwise, say how instead of just saying that what I observe "isn't true"...